# vsts build Agent Shell provide password

Tags: shell, solr, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently creating a build agent for our DevOps.
With the agent I want to stop solr via shell script on the unix server. The problem is, I need to insert a password, to stop the service.

Is there a simple way to provide the password in the shell script? The current script:

```
service solr stop
```

throws the following error:

```
2020-03-12T12:50:27.0480993Z Successfully connected.
2020-03-12T12:50:27.0483958Z service solr stop
2020-03-12T12:50:29.7903365Z 
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8193011Z ##[error]Failed to stop solr.service: Interactive authentication required.
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8208401Z 
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8208979Z 
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8209589Z ##[error]See system logs and 'systemctl status solr.service' for details.
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8209971Z 
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8210587Z ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
2020-03-12T12:50:29.8341862Z ##[section]Finishing: stop solr
```

I also tried to provide the password on the script, like:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S service solr stop
```

It works on the server locally, but the buildserver throws:

```
2020-03-12T12:52:17.9543478Z Successfully connected.
2020-03-12T12:52:17.9545108Z echo *** | sudo -S service solr stop
2020-03-12T12:52:18.9946984Z ##[error][sudo] password for ***: 
2020-03-12T12:52:23.4808034Z ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
2020-03-12T12:52:23.5019910Z ##[section]Finishing: stop solr
```

Any other ideas how I could remotely stop solr with a shell script?

Comment: Might be that can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903802/secure-way-to-run-sudo-commands-in-azure-devops-ssh-task

Comment: That link was useful. But I find a solution without changing the user or group policies. I will answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned I found a solution and posted it in another post. Here's the answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666738/5835745